# Using LDR assembly instruction for ARM v7 on Keil Uvision

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I am trying to write a simple program to find the largest integer in an array. I actually got this code from a textbook so it's not my own, but anyways when I simulate it in keil simulator it doesn't run as expected. I don't think the problem is in the code itself, but here it is:

`

```
        AREA myData,DATA
        ALIGN
array   DCD -1,5,3,8,10,23,6,5,2,-10
size    DCD 10
    
        AREA findmax,CODE
        EXPORT __main
        ALIGN
        ENTRY
        
__main  PROC
        
        ;Identify array size
        LDR r6, =size
        LDR r6,[r6]
        SUB r6,r6,#1
        
        ;Initialize maxvalue and maxlocation
        LDR r7,=array
        LDR r3,[r7]     ;Default max
        MOV r4,#0       ;Max location
        
        ;loop function
        MOV r5,#0       ;Loop index
loop    CMP r5,r6
        BGE stop
        LDR r8, [r7, r5, LSL#2]     ;Load r8 with array[i]
        CMP r8,r3
        MOVGT r3,r8     ;Update max value if array(i)>max. Conditionally executed instruction
        MOVGT r4,r5     ;Update max location. Conditionally executed instruction
        ADD r5,r5,#1
        B   loop
        
stop    B   stop        
        
        ENDP
        END
```

`

I am looking in the debugger and it seems the problem is this line of code:

`LDR r6,[r6]`

is read as

`LDR r6,[0x00]`

[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TSIq.png)

It works if use 'MOV' instruction and type in the value myself but not with LDR.

What am I doing wrong?

As it has been pointed out in the comments I should verify the ldr, =size indeed loads the memory address, and I think it does ([Honestly I'm not entirely sure how to view it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKleM.png) but in the memory window that memory space has no value. The program still doesn't run properly. The program branches and stops at the first iteration of the loop because the size of the array stored in r6 is 0

Comment: There is nothing wrong here.  `ldr r6, [r6]` is exactly the same as `ldr r6, [r6, #0x00]`, because `r6` plus zero always equals `r6`.  Note however that it is not at all the same as: `ldr r6, [0x00]` which is what you misinterpreted it as.  Your problem must be somewhere else.  I'll vote to close this question as a simple mis-reading, but if you can identify a real problem please do ask another question or edit this one.

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong about the problem but it’s still not working as it should. The program branches at the first iteration of the loop because the index r5 will be greater than the size of the array . Which is 0. I will edit my question

Comment: Why not just store 9 as the size? Or better yet write it as 10-1?

Comment: Is that the exact code you are running? Since you are in a debugger, verify `ldr r6, =size` loads the address of the `size` variable and that the value in memory is in fact `10` as defined.

Comment: I could do that and it works. But thats not how the book  I’m learning from does it, and I want to understand why it can/can’t work like that

Comment: Yes, this the code I'm running. I edited my question and added more details

Comment: `size    DCD 10` should definitely put `10` into that location. What is the address of `array`? Assuming your data starts at `0x20000000` then the 10 items would give address `0x200000028` for `size` which is 4 bytes lower.